# Store array as a value within Pandas column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data set with two columns of categorical label data (NBA Team names). What I want to do is use one hot encoding to generate a binary, 1D vector as an array representing each team. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
one_hot_encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
table["Teams"] = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(table["Teams"])
```

The encoder works appropriately, and it generates the arrays accordingly. In other words,

```
one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(table["Teams"])
```

generates the following properly:

[Link to encoder result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhxkA.png)

However, when I try to store the array into the column, as follows:

```
table["Teams"] = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(table["Teams"])
```

It seems like it's not being saved properly.

[Link to data frame result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BO9L.png)

Instead, it looks as if the column is just taking the first value of each array, and not storing the entire array. How should I go about resolving this?

Comment: Could your paste your sample data instead of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need convert `2d` array to `list`s:

```
table = pd.DataFrame({"Teams":list('aaasdffds')})

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
one_hot_encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()

table["Teams"] = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(table["Teams"]).tolist()
print (table)
          Teams
0  [1, 0, 0, 0]
1  [1, 0, 0, 0]
2  [1, 0, 0, 0]
3  [0, 0, 0, 1]
4  [0, 1, 0, 0]
5  [0, 0, 1, 0]
6  [0, 0, 1, 0]
7  [0, 1, 0, 0]
8  [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

But store arrays or lists to one column is not recommended because not possible use vectorized methods/functions, better is create `DataFrame`:

```
table = pd.DataFrame(one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(table["Teams"]), 
                     columns=one_hot_encoder.classes_)
print (table)

   a  d  f  s
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  1
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  0  1  0
6  0  0  1  0
7  0  1  0  0
8  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing you need a list within your DataFrame. You can store the arrays as a list, pandas wont modify it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoded_array = mlb.fit_transform(table['Teams'])
table['Teams'] = [ [encoded_array [i,:]] for i in range(table.shape[0]) ]
```

Comment: OP need new column filled with array, so your question dont answer it. It is recommedation only, same  principe in my answer.